# Importar arquivo script externo no Vue.js após o build!

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho a seguinte situação, preciso enviar somente o build(dist) de um projeto Vue para o cliente, porem ele vai precisar criar funções dinâmicas para validar alguns campos do um formulário, tenho a seguinte estrutura..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quando faço o build ele cria essa pasta `scripts` com o arquivo `index.js` dentro, e la é onde vai ser adicionadas posteriormente as funções para validar os campos.. essas funções vão ser alteradas periodicamente com novas regras e validações, como consigo já deixar esse arquivo importado dentro do projeto? e utilizar ele como uma Função local dentro de um componente do Vue?

Obrigado!

Comment: Amigo se entendi bem a pergunta, o cliente não vai conseguir fazer nada com os arquivos gerados após o buid, o build minifica todos os arquivos.

Comment: Mais alterando o arquivo fora do depois do build.. isso se reflete na aplicação, já fiz esse teste aqui deu certo.. só estou tentando entender qual a melhor forma de importar este arquivo para aplicação!